# Javascript | Page Turn does not work on local system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working a page turn project, i have downloaded turn.min.js on local, but the page does not turn in the local machine.

I have put windows load and document ready functions and still does not work

It works Perfect on http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/A9a7E/5215/#&togetherjs=ryESxehywM

But does not work on my local...

HTML

```
<div id="flipbook">
    <div class="hard"> Turn.js </div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div> Page 1 </div>
    <div> Page 2 </div>
    <div> Page 3 </div>
    <div> Page 4 </div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#flipbook").turn({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        autoCenter: true
    });
```

CSS:

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}

#flipbook{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}

#flipbook .page{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:white;
    line-height:300px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#flipbook .page-wrapper{
    -webkit-perspective:2000px;
    -moz-perspective:2000px;
    -ms-perspective:2000px;
    -o-perspective:2000px;
    perspective:2000px;
}

#flipbook .hard{
    background:#ccc !important;
    color:#333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#flipbook .odd{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0.95, #FFF), color-stop(1, #DADADA));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;

}

#flipbook .even{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.95, #fff), color-stop(1, #dadada));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for any errors? And the net panel for any resources that might not have loaded properly?

Answer (score 0):

i added the
`<script src="http://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js"></script>`
 in my code and this solved the problem